# How to show custom keyboard created by using subclass of Keyboard

Tags: android

I've designed a custom keyboard by subclassing it on Keyboard class.

```
public class MyKeyboard extends Keyboard
{
     //layout and key stuffs
}
```

Now i want to know how show MyKeyboard and hide default keyboard programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for you

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615